# VSCode Extension: Command 'Hello World' resulted in an error (command 'vscode-err-reproduce.helloWorld' not found)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

###### Problem Description:

I tried creating VS Code extension using the sample extension (yo code)  provided in the documentation. I chose "typescript" as it's type of extension, while creating it.
When  I tried to run the extension, I get an error message .

```
Command 'Hello World' resulted in an error (command 'vscode-err-reproduce.helloWorld' not found)
```

```
Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.vscode-err-reproduce' failed: Cannot find module
 '/oct/vscode-extn-ts-error/vscode-err-reproduce/out/extension.js' Require stack: - /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js - /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/bootstrap-amd.js - /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/bootstrap-fork.js.
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "outDir": "out",
        "lib": [
            "ES2020"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true   /* enable all strict type-checking options */
        /* Additional Checks */
        // "noImplicitReturns": true, /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
        // "noUnusedParameters": true,  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode-test"
    ]
}
```

Comment: try a sample extension from the repo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is due to the compilation not running or failing to run at the launch of the extension.  Hence .js file not getting created on /out/* directory

1. I solved the issue, by manually running tsc --watch from the root directory.
2. I thought, the launch of the extension by default trigger the compilation, but that wasn't the case.
3. The product documentation says,"press F5. This will compile and run the extension in a new Extension Development Host window."  However, this isn't the case for me.  Not sure, where it was actually failing .
4. I've opened up an bug with Microsoft for this issue.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/issues/510

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, do not forget that the `yo generator` created a sub folder inside your current directory.
Ensure that you run the tsc flag inside the sub folder. Watch out for the `out` folder. It should be created.

Answer (score 3):

I created the project inside a sub-folder and got this error, but closing VS Code and reopening the actual sub-folder worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33321265)

Answer (score 0):

Check typescript installation before execute the extension

`npm install -g typescript`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For me, I ran `npm install -g javascript` and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please try opening your extension directly, without placing it inside any subfolder. This workaround has resolved the error for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

uninstall vscode then reinstall it work for me